# Why is the coefficient for my interaction term in my GLM equal to NA?

Tags: r, model, glm

I ran the following model:

```
model <- glm(DV ~ IV1*IV2, data = data, family="poisson")
```

And I received the following results:

```
Call:
glm(formula = DV ~ IV1 * IV2, family = "poisson", 
    data = data)

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)        0.465506   0.053783   8.655   <2e-16
IV1            -0.005388   0.048897  -0.110    0.912
IV2         0.540514   0.032046  16.867   <2e-16
IV1:IV2        NA         NA      NA       NA
                     
(Intercept)       ***
IV1               
IV2        ***
IV1:IV2    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3029.4  on 2153  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2705.6  on 2151  degrees of freedom
  (364 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 7393.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

My first thought was that these two variables must be collinear...

```
table(data$IV1, data$IV2, useNA = "always")
      
          0    1 <NA>
  0     331  198    0
  1    1278  711    0
  <NA>    0    0    0
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case.

I can't reproduce the entire data frame here, but I was wondering if folks have any idea of what could be going on here? Is there anything else I should check?

This is what it looks like when I use the `with()` command:

```
with(survey_clean, table(IV1, IV2, DV, useNA = "always"))
, , DV = 0

     IV2
IV1   0   1
    0   0  15
    1 398  47

, , DV = 1

     IV2
IV1   0   1
    0   0  12
    1 266  85

, , DV = 2

     IV2
IV1   0   1
    0   0  50
    1 259 145

, , DV = 3

     IV2
IV1   0   1
    0   0  52
    1 131 163

, , DV = 4

     IV2
IV1   0   1
    0   0  67
    1 204 260

, , DV = NA

      IV2
IV1    0   1 <NA>
  0    331   2    0
  1     20  11    0
  <NA>   0   0    0
```

Comment: `(364 observations deleted due to missingness)` If you remove missing data, what does that `table` look like? I am guessing this is missingness in the response variable

Comment: try `with(data, table (IV1, IV2, DV))`

Comment: @BenBolker I added the output into my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Examining the breakdown of your `with(survey_clean, table(...))` output, we can see that the `{IV1=0, IV2=0}` condition **only** occurs when `DV` is `NA` (i.e., that cell contains 0 for `DV`==0-4 and is only non-zero when `DV` is `NA`. Since these cases are discarded by `glm()` by default (the only *simple* way to deal with missing data in R is **complete case analysis**, which discards observations with `NA` value in any of the model variables), the data set for the model only has three combinations of predictor variables (`IV[1,2]` = {0,1}, {1,0}, or {1,1}), so only three coefficients total can be estimated.

In hindsight, the issue would be even clearer if you ran

```r
with(survey_clean, table(IV1, IV2, is.na(DV)))
```

(which would give tables only separated by whether `DV` was `NA` or not, not for each separate value of `DV`)

---

What you should do about this situation is more of a statistical than a programming question.

- you could stick with the current results, which basically say "I don't have enough information to estimate the interaction parameter"
- you **could** assume (as discussed in comments) that all of the `IV1=0, IV2=0` cases have a response (`DV`) of zero, **but**: (1) that seems like an awfully strong assumption [but I don't know anything about your problem] (2) that will lead to a further problem of *complete separation* (your estimate of the effect of the interaction will be *infinite*; see the `brglm2` package and questions here and on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) for what to do about it ...) (3) you could 'unfold' your two-way factorial into a one-way design by making a new variable based on `interaction(IV1, IV2, drop = TRUE)` and estimating those three coefficients.

Comment: When I do complete case analysis, I get NA. If I am pretty certain that when IV1 and IV2 are both equal to 0, the DV is likely to be 0 as well, is there a way to justify the choice to populate DV==NA with 0?

Comment: Is there a different model I should consider for this distribution?